# pandas Series.str.contains extracted what shouldn't have appeared

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data like this

[data img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1CFi.png)

I'm extracting rows with `1.1.1.1` by `Series.str.contains(pttn, regex=False)`

```
pttn = '1.1.1.1'
dd = pd.Series(['1.1.1.1, 2.22.3.107','1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2, 1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2, 1.1.1.14','1.1.1.15','1.1.1.100','1.1.1.101','1.1.1.109'])
dd[dd.str.contains(pttn, regex=False, na=False)]
```

and I got the unexpected result

```
0    1.1.1.1, 2.22.3.107
1                1.1.1.1
2       2.2.2.2, 1.1.1.1
3      2.2.2.2, 1.1.1.14
4               1.1.1.15
5              1.1.1.100
6              1.1.1.101
7              1.1.1.109
dtype: object
```

but actually what I want only is

```
0    1.1.1.1, 2.22.3.107
1                1.1.1.1
2       2.2.2.2, 1.1.1.1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

```
>>> dd[dd.str.split(', ').explode().loc[lambda x: x == pttn].index]
0    1.1.1.1, 2.22.3.107
1                1.1.1.1
2       2.2.2.2, 1.1.1.1
dtype: object
```

---

**Old answer**

You are looking for `str.fullmatch`:

```
>>> dd[dd.str.fullmatch(pttn)]
0    1.1.1.1
dtype: object
```

Or

```
>>> df[dd == pttn]
0    1.1.1.1
dtype: object
```

The advantage with `str.fullmatch` is you can use a regular expression or control the case, sensitive or not.

Comment: @zhangjq. I updated my answer according your edit. Can your check it please?

Comment: cool!!!! Thank you and you really help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
newdd = dd[dd == pttn]
```

Your solution uses `contains`, and indeed, all values in `dd` *contain* the string `'1.1.1.1'`, so they all match.